# Call non static method dynamically

Tags: php, static, callback

i tried to call non static method like that:

```
call_user_func_array(array("Notifications", "getNots"), $params)
```

and i got error:
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method...

the function is:

```
class Notifications {
    public function getNots($limit, $test = 0) {
    }
}
```

what to do?

actually i tried to built function that got html code of html page
and replace all texts like that:

```
{{ Notifications.getNotes(3) }}
```

to method return...

tnx a lot

Comment: Did you try this: $notifications = new Notifications();
call_user_func_array(array($notifications, "getNots"), $params));

Comment: i got the object from another object like this:
object template--> variable object notificiation

Answer (score 2):

To do this with a non-static function, you need to instantiate a Notification object (if not alrady done, then pass it into call_user_func_array() as the first value in the callback array. Something like this:

```
$notifications = new Notification();
call_user_func_array(array($notifications, "getNots"), $params);
```

If already instantiated, you pass the instance, rather than the class name.

Comment: Why use `call_user_func_array`?

Comment: You'll have to ask the original poster. I'd use for a case when I needed to call a set of methods, and the specific methods called depended on some prior user input. It can be simpler than adding a switch or a bunch of if conditionals in that case.