# Deprecated: Non-static method. How can I separate this in Routing Class?

Tags: php, oop

I did a Laravel-like routing system. Routing works as super. But when I call the controller I get a Deprecated: Non-static method error. How can I prevent this error? I did a lot of experiments but couldn't find a solution.

```php
class Router {

    protected static $url;
    protected $callback, $params;

    public function __construct($url) {

        if(!empty($url)) {
            self::$url = trim('/', $url);
        }

        if(!function_exists('view')) {
            function view($parameters, $var = []) {
                restore_include_path();
                Blade::addPath(VIEW_DIR);
                print Blade::render($parameters , $var);
            }
        }
    }

    public static function currentURL() {
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }

    public static function mainRouter($url, $callback) {

        $url = preg_replace('/\{(.*?)\}/', '(.*)', $url);

        if(preg_match('@^'.$url.'$@', self::currentURL(), $parameters)) {

            unset($parameters[0]);

            if(gettype($callback) == 'object') {
                call_user_func_array($callback, $parameters);
            }

            if(gettype($callback) == 'string') {
                if(is_array(explode('@', $callback))) {
                    list($control, $method) = explode('@', $callback);
                    if(file_exists(CONTROLLER_DIR . $control . '.php')) {
                        call_user_func_array(['App\\Controller\\'.$control, $method], $parameters);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static function get($url, $callback){
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == strtoupper(__FUNCTION__)) {
            $url = addslashes(strip_tags($url));
            Router::mainRouter($url, $callback);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Routing

```php
    Router::get('/b/{name}', 'HomeController@index'); // faulty part

    Router::get('/a/{name}', function ($name) {
        return view('index'); // Works perfect
    });
```

---

Controller

```php
class HomeController {

    public function index($name) {
        echo Controller::view('index');
    }

}
```

#### incoming error

Deprecated: Non-static method App\Controller\HomeController::index() should not be called statically in

Comment: You need to `new` up an instance of your controller to call methods non-statically.

Comment: I know it was done this way. But I can not make the logic in my example.

Comment: If you need a coding example, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33201460/3095084